# c++ function return type is incomplete when I try to return a struct

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

This is my function:

```
bsoncxx::types::b_utf8 read_command(bsoncxx::document::view* bson_message) {
    ...
    return (*tag).get_utf8(tag->key());
}
```

I'm using `get_utf8()` which according to its [specification](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/current/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1element.html#a56d1481d9573048f8623e81a7ce468d6) shall return a `types::b_utf8` element. But I'm getting the following error:

```
error: return type 'struct bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_utf8' is incomplete
 bsoncxx::types::b_utf8 read_command(bsoncxx::document::view* bson_message) {
```

I can see clearly that the `b_utf8` `struct` is inside the `types` namespace which is inside the `bsoncxx` namespace. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It says is incomplete. Sounds like you have not included the header where it's defined.

Comment: Include the header file containing definition of the missing struct